# Web authentication using LDAP and Apache?

Tags: authentication, web-development, apache-http-server, ldap

I am working on a project of setting up a web administered inventory database for my work (or if they don't want it then i'll enjoy learning about it) and hit the problem of allowing only authorized users to access the website (In its testing/development phase, I allow all people to navigate to the website to add entries to the database and query it).  I am trying to make it so only particular users in the domain (Active Directory) are allowed to access the website after they are queried about their credentials.  I read that Apache (I am using a LAMP server) has a means of asking visitors to the website to provide LDAP credentials in order to gain access to the site, but I wasn't sure if that was exactly what I was looking for.  If anyone has experience in the LDAP configurations for Apache that I mentioned or any other means of securely authenticating with websites I would greatly appreciate advice or a direction to go

Thank you!

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Didn't know I had to review answers.  Thanks for the heads up

Comment: why don't you use php (or your language of choice) to connect and authenticate through LDAP. You can see how it is done in media wiki for example.

Answer (score 1):

apache has a module - mod_authnz_ldap for ldap authentication.

There are many how-to's describing how to implement it.

http://www.held-im-ruhestand.de/software/apache-ldap-active-directory-authentication
http://yonitg.com/apache-active-directory-authentication/
http://www.netexpertise.eu/en/apache/authentication-against-active-directory.html

Docs for the module: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html

Comment: When a user makes a connection to the web server that Apache is on (provided that the LDAP module you mentioned is being used), will the user be asked for their credentials before they are allowed to continue to the website?  If that is the case then I will certainly pursue using the modules.

Comment: if you set the authentication as being needed to access the root page, then yes.